# How to replace by array terms

Tags: php, str-replace

I need to replace words from text

```
    $test = "Nordman Nokian NORDMAN 4 XL";
$replaces = array("Amtel " ,"Bridgestone " ,"Continental " ,"Cordiant " ,"Dunlop " ,"Formula " ,"Gislaved " ,"Kingstar " ,"BFGoodrich " ,"GoodYear " ,"Hankook " ,"Headway " ,"Fulda " ,"HIFLY " ,"Kumho " ,"Gremax " ,"Matador " ,"Michelin " ,"Rosava " ,"Nankang " ,"Nokian " ,"Nordman Nokian " ,"Pirelli " ,"Radial " ,"Sava " ,"Tigar " ,"Toyo " ,"Viatti " ,"Maxxis " ,"Yokohama ");
echo str_replace($replaces, "", $test);
// return Nordman NORDMAN 4 XL
```

**the desired result**

```
// return NORDMAN 4 XL
```

I apologize for the change in question, added the code which is not working replacement

Comment: Your return in this case would be "Hellow world this".. Since "Hellow world" is not "Hello world", so it won't be replaced..

Comment: Do you mean to have put "Hellow" rather than "Hello" on your first line?

Comment: If you want to return "Hellow world this", remove "Hellow world" from your array of strings to replace.

Comment: The "Nokian " get's replaced first, meaning then that there is no more "Nordman Nokian ".

Comment: Why you changed your question dramatically? The answers before your edit are for first revision, you should have posted this code first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you have the string `Nokian` being replaced before the string `Nordman Nokian`.  Because the single word `Nokian` is being matched first, the string is being transformed to Nordman NORDMAN 4 XL, and `str_replace` is unable to match the string `Nordman Nokian`.  Just switch the order of your array items

I.E.
`..."Nordman Nokian ","Nokian "...`

Comment: This will work, but if this were me, I'd just split off the first word by space as all the manufactures the OP has are single words, except for the Nordman Nokian.  Probably add a special case for that one . . .

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure there's a better method to accomplish the OPs task.  Personally, I would use `preg_replace`.  But I'm just answering why the OPs code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have typo in your `array`:

```
$replaces = array("Hellow world","Like");
```

Now the `str_replace` returns `this`

Comment: I apologize for the change in question, added the code which is not working replacement

Answer (score 0):

Refer - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Here, the array is the words we want to replace, second parameter is the string we want to replace with and the third param is the haystack of string. This should work

```
// Provides: Hll Wrld f PHP
$vowels = array("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U");
$onlyconsonants = str_replace($vowels, "", "Hello World of PHP");
```

Comment: I apologize for the change in question, added the code which is not working replacement